# How to verify a domain for Google App Engine when you only control the subdomain

Tags: google-app-engine

It is common to host research websites as a subdomain under the department's domain. For example: myapp.cs.myuniv.edu.

We have an App Engine site we want to do this with and my department is happy to add a DNS record. But when I try to verify myapp.cs.myuniv.edu Google wants me to add a TXT record to myuniv.edu, obviously not something that makes any sense for us.

How can I verify that I control myapp.cs.myuniv.edu when I don't control myuniv.edu?

In case it matters I am following the verification process in the Google Developers Console under Compute > App Engine > Settings > Custom Domains > Add a custom domain.

Comment: Looks like it is not currently possible, just checked the google apps -- they ask you to verify naked domain name as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iframe the GAE app into a page on your subdomain and avoid verification all together.

Comment: A reasonable potential workaround, though you lose connection with the user's address bar, and need to maintain an extra shadow site.